# Ansible XML to configure Jira Server.xml

Tags: xml, ansible, jira, server.xml

Currently, I am attempting to use ansible to change fields in my "server.xml" file.  Specifically, the options listed within the "Connector" element.  I have posted an example of my "server.xml" with field content altered to remove identifying information.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on"/>
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

<Service name="Catalina">

               <Connector port="8080" proxyName="test.somewebsite.com" proxyport="443" scheme="https" secure="true" relaxedPathChars="[]|" relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" connectionTimeout="20000" enableLookups="false"
               maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" protocol="HTTP/1.1" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" redirectPort="8443"
               acceptCount="100" disableUploadTimeout="true" bindOnInit="false"/>


    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

            <Context path="" docBase="${catalina.home}/atlassian-jira" reloadable="false" useHttpOnly="true">
                <Resource name="UserTransaction" auth="Container" type="javax.transaction.UserTransaction"
                          factory="org.objectweb.jotm.UserTransactionFactory" jotm.timeout="60"/>
                <Manager pathname=""/>
                <JarScanner scanManifest="false"/>
            </Context>

        </Host>
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
               pattern="%a %{jira.request.id}r %{jira.request.username}r %t &quot;%m %U%q %H&quot; %s %b %D &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot; &quot;%{jira.request.assession.id}r&quot;"/>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

I am using the following Ansible to make changes. Most of my adjustments would be performed on the Connector attributes such as changing proxyname or removing it altogether. Unfortunately, the only thing I found similar was namespaces however this code does not use conventional namespaces. What am I doing wrong?

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: Update Scheme Option in Connector
    xml:
      path: /home/test/server.xml
      xpath: /Server/Service/Connector/@scheme
      value: https

  - name: Update Secure Option in Connector
    xml:
      path: /home/test/server.xml
      xpath: /Server/Service/Connector/@secure
      value: true


  - name: Remove the Unused attributes
    xml:
      path: /home/test/server.xml
      xpath: "{{ item }}"
      state: absent
    loop:
      - "/Server/Service/Connector/@proxyName"
      - "/Server/Service/Connector/@proxyport"
      - "/Server/Service/Connector/@secure"
      - "/Server/Service/Connector/@redirectPort"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html), you must provide the attribute name in the separate [`attribute`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html#parameter-attribute) option when using [`value`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html#parameter-value) to set it. Note also that the `true` value must be quoted or you will get a python error complaining you passed a bool instead of a string

This is your fixed set of tasks:

```yaml
  tasks:
  - name: Update Scheme Option in Connector
    xml:
      path: /home/test/server.xml
      xpath: /Server/Service/Connector
      attribute: scheme
      value: https

  - name: Update Secure Option in Connector
    xml:
      path: /home/test/server.xml
      xpath: /Server/Service/Connector
      attribute: secure
      value: "true"

  - name: Remove the Unused attributes
    xml:
      path: /home/test/server.xml
      xpath: "{{ item }}"
      state: absent
    loop:
      - "/Server/Service/Connector/@proxyName"
      - "/Server/Service/Connector/@proxyport"
      - "/Server/Service/Connector/@secure"
      - "/Server/Service/Connector/@redirectPort"
```

Comment: Thank you I actually finally came to this same conclusion and it worked.  Now I am just trying to figure out confluence as it is a little more complicated.